# Is convolving $f(t)$ with a unit step function the same as integrating $f(t)$?

Tags: integration, convolution

Convolving two unit step functions yields

$$u(t) \ast u(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(\tau)u(t-\tau) \ \text{d}\tau =  tu(t)$$

This result is identical to $\int_{-\infty}^t u(\tau) \ \text{d}\tau= tu(t)$ which suggests that convolving a function with a unit step function is the same as integrating the function.

I have not been able to find any proofs or mentions of this, however.

Can someone confirm/disprove that convolving with a unit step function is the same as integrating?

Comment: The equation $\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(t)dt = tu(t)$ does not make sense. The LHS is a definite integral (it does not exist since the integral is divergent) while the RHS is a function of $t$.

Comment: @QuercusRobur My bad, it was supposed to be an indefinite integral. I have ammended the question.

Comment: I meant the equation in the sentence "This result is identical to ...". This has not been edited.

Comment: @QuercusRobur Yes it has. It now reads "This result is identical to $\int u(t) \ \text{d}t = tu(t)$ which suggests that convolving a function with a unit step function is the same as integrating the function."

Comment: Sorry, my bad. However, it still does not make sense. In the LHS, $t$ is an integration variable. In the RHS, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and the integral $\int_{-\infty}^t f(\tau)d\tau$ exists for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then you obviously have

$(u*f)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)u(t-\tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^tf(\tau)d\tau. $

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Is $\int_{-\infty}^t f(\tau) \ \text{d}\tau = \int f(t) \ \text{d}t $? If so, then yes, I guess.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by $\int f(t)dt$. You don't indicate what the integration limits are.

Comment: It is an indefinite integral.

Comment: Well, then it's not true. See also my recent comment to your question. From my equation you can see that $\lim_{t \to + \infty} (u*f)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)d\tau$.